# How do I upgrade Amazon Linux?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade, software-updates, amazon-linux

Is Amazon Linux based on CentOS 6?  I want to upgrade my Amazon Linux instance

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ uname -a
Linux sandbox2.evo-text.com 4.9.38-16.33.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 20 01:31:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

to CentOS 7 but I'm confused about how to do that.  I can "yum install update" but I'm wondering if I have to update my "Centos.repo" file, located at /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
enabled=1
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=0

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=updates
enabled=1
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=0

[CentOS-base]
name=CentOS-6 - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates
[CentOS-updates]
name=CentOS-6 - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=updates
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[CentOS-extras]
name=CentOS-6 - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=extras
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Do I need to change the contents of the file in order to upgrade my Amazon Linux instance, and if so, what do they need to be?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS isn't meant to be upgraded between major releases, and AWS will tell you to destroy the instance and spin up a new one using a CentOS 7 AMI.